# PEP8 に関するエラーの意味が分からない

Tags: python, python3

PEP8のドキュメントに目を通したんですが、初めててということもあり、
正直どう修正していいのか分からないので、指摘して下さると助かります。

エラーメッセージ

> too many blank lines

エラーメッセージ箇所

```
def popluar_article(query1):
```

コード

```
def popluar_article(query1):
    db = psycopg2.connect("dbname=news")
    c = db.cursor()
    c.execute(query1)
    results = c.fetchall()
    for e in results:
        print ("{0} -- {1} views".format(e[0], e[1]))
    db.close()
```

55行目から57行目が79文字を超えているので、
３行にしたんですが、下記のエラーが返ってきました。

エラーメッセージ

> line break before binary operator 
>   missing whitespace after ‘,’

エラーメッセージ箇所

```
print (date.strftime('%B %d, %Y')
       + ' ' + '--' + ' '
       + str (round(per_err,1)) + '%' + ' ' + 'errors')
```

コード

```
def error_percent(query3):
    db = psycopg2.connect("dbname=news")
    c = db.cursor()
    c.execute(query3)
    results = c.fetchall()
    for e in results:
        date = (e[0])
        per_err = (e[1])
        print (date.strftime('%B %d, %Y')
               + ' ' + '--' + ' '
               + str (round(per_err,1)) + '%' + ' ' + 'errors')
    db.close()
```

エラーメッセージ

> no newline at end of file

エラーメッセージ箇所

```
error_percent(query3)
```

コード

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    print ("The 3 most poplular articles of all time are:")
    popluar_article(query1)
    print("\n")
    print ("The most popular article authors of all time are")
    poplular_author(query2)
    print("\n")
    print ("Days did more than 1% of requests lead to errors")
    error_percent(query3)
```

Comment: エラーの英語の意味はご存知ですか？

Comment: はい、意味は分かるのですが、どう具体的に修正するか分かりません。

Answer (score 2):

エラー内容そのままに修正すれば良いです。

- too many blank lines

  - おそらく関数定義の前の空行の数が多いです。削除してください。（[参考](http://pep8-ja.readthedocs.io/ja/latest/#id11)）
- line break before binary operator

  - ここでいう二項演算子は `+` を指しています。`+` の前で改行しているためエラーになっているので、`+` の後で改行するようにしてください。
- missing whitespace after ‘,’

  - `round(per_err,1)` の部分です。
- no newline at end of file

  - ファイル末尾に改行が無いことを意味しています。ファイルの最後に空行を入れてください（実際、これをしないと Python 以外の場合でも上手く処理できないときがあります）。

Comment: too many blank lines　関数前後を2行空けることでエラーがなくなりました。no newline at endile ファイルの最後に空行を入れることでエラーがなくなりました。